# We arrived at the venue before the show starts - Do we use "starts" or "started"?

Tags: tense

The show starts at 7, and we arrived at 4, so the show has not started yet.

How can we express this logic?

**Example 1**

> We arrived at the venue before the show **starts/started**.

Do we use **starts** or **started**?

Does this example make sense?

Comment: Do you want to know how to express this exact situation, or do you want to know the grammar for expressing something that happened before another event when that other event is still in the future?

Comment: I would like to know about the second one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the arrival was in the past and the show will start in the future, it is better to say

> We arrived at the venue before time and the show is yet to start.
>
> or
>
> We arrived at the venue before time and the show "will start" (or
> "will be starting") on "time" (you may choose to specify the time).

You are combining past tense and future tense in the same sentence, so you have to be careful so that what you are saying makes sense to the listener.

You can also use this sentence

> We arrived at the venue well before the start of the show.

The use of "well before" in the sentence, only means "start of the show" was very late compared to arrival, but it still is unclear whether "start of the show" was in the past or will be in the future. It is better to avoid the ambiguity and use unambiguous constructions if you are not doing that on purpose.

Supposing you are in the present telling about the past in a time frame in the past: (you are at this moment today, describing the events of yesterday placing yourself at 12 PM, you arrived at 11 AM and the show was to start at 2 PM): then it is okay to use the following sentence.

> We arrived at the venue before time and the show was yet to start.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is there is no clean way to complete the sentence as you've laid it out. Using simple present is bad grammar, and using simple past has the wrong meaning.

The closest is to replace the verb "start" with the noun "start":

> We arrived at the venue before **the start of the show**.

Another option is to use present perfect with present simple. The grammar is good, but it sounds awkward:

> **We've arrived** at the venue before the show **starts.**

If your intent with this question is just to express this situation, then the simplest way is to omit either "arrive" or "start" entirely:

> We're here and the show hasn't started yet. *(It's understood that we arrived)*
> We've arrived early. *(It's understood the show hasn't started yet)*